# How to use cocoapods locally?

Tags: xcode, git, local, cocoapods

**I tried to use `cocoa pods` locally but it failed with an error.**

I installed a local repo called `MyPods` and didn't have problems with that.
I did

```
 $ pod repo add MyPods file://localhost/Users/colas/MyDeveloper/MyPods/.
```

Then, I added in `MyPod` a `.podspec` (in the folder `/MyPods/MyLib/0.0.1`.
The `.podspec` file looks like this

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|


  s.name         = "MyLib"
  s.version      = "0.0.1"

  s.source       = { :path => 'file://localhost/Users/colas/MyLib/0.0.1/MyLib'}

  s.source_files  = 'MyLib/**/*.{h,m}'


end
```

Then, I want to use this `pod` in a project. Here's my `Podfile`

```
platform :ios, '5.0'

xcodeproj 'testMyLib.xcodeproj'

pod 'MyLib'
```

But I have the error:

```
Pod::Downloader::DownloaderError - Unsupported download strategy `{:path=>...
```

**Is there a way to manage my own pods on my machine?**

Comment: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/967 check this out